# How could I detect if an element is touching another element's border?

Tags: javascript

```
function touching(object1, object2) {
    var object1LeftSide = object1.offsetLeft;
    var object1RightSide = object1.offsetLeft + object1.offsetWidth;
    var object1TopSide = object1.offsetTop;
    var object1BottomSide = object1.offsetTop + object1.offsetHeight;

    var object2LeftSide = object2.offsetLeft;
    var object2RightSide = object2.offsetLeft + object2.offsetWidth;
    var object2TopSide = object2.offsetTop;
    var object2BottomSide = object2.offsetTop + object2.offsetHeight;

    var objectsTouchingHorizontally = object1RightSide >= object2LeftSide && object1LeftSide <= object2RightSide;
    var objectsTouchingVertically = object1BottomSide >= object2TopSide && object1TopSide <= object2BottomSide;

    return objectsTouchingHorizontally && objectsTouchingVertically;
}
```

I am using this function to detect if two elements are touching, what should I change? I've tried just about everything.

I am trying to create an app to simulate a ball bouncing.

Comment: How are you moving the elements? chaning their top/left property or using transform/translate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! So, I wanted to make some balls bouncing in a little box for fun, and I thought I needed to check if the ball was touching the border of the box before it bounced off the wall. I was using left/top positioning to move the balls, and I figured out the correct left/top pixels I needed to check for before bouncing the ball.

Thanks for the help and quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your function appears to be working, check the snippet below:

```js
function touching(object1, object2) {
  var object1LeftSide = object1.offsetLeft;
  var object1RightSide = object1.offsetLeft + object1.offsetWidth;
  var object1TopSide = object1.offsetTop;
  var object1BottomSide = object1.offsetTop + object1.offsetHeight;

  var object2LeftSide = object2.offsetLeft;
  var object2RightSide = object2.offsetLeft + object2.offsetWidth;
  var object2TopSide = object2.offsetTop;
  var object2BottomSide = object2.offsetTop + object2.offsetHeight;

  var objectsTouchingHorizontally =
    object1RightSide >= object2LeftSide && object1LeftSide <= object2RightSide;
  var objectsTouchingVertically =
    object1BottomSide >= object2TopSide && object1TopSide <= object2BottomSide;

  return objectsTouchingHorizontally && objectsTouchingVertically;
}

console.log(touching(document.getElementById('img1'), document.getElementById('img2')))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <img
      id="img2"
      style="margin: -10px"
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    />
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```